# Как вывести четное число записей из бд

Tags: php, mysql

Собственно в название сам вопрос. Есть бд, в таблице записи "последние новости". Мне нужно вывести парное число записей, т.е кратное двум, так как у меня слайдер переключает по 2 новости. КАк можно это сделать?

Comment: Слово кратное значит делиться нацело на 2. У меня в базе примерно 83 записи. как вы считаете? я хочу вывести 2 записи или все же 82?

Comment: чет бред какой-то. Вы собираетесь при каждом переключении слайдера делать еще 1 запрос к БД? Лучше загрузите все 83 записи из БД, затем уже делайте с ними то, что хотите, на фронтэнде. Если используете ORM, то, к примеру, в eloquent есть метод chunk(), который после выборки данных может разделить данные. Писать чистый sql к БД при наличии более мощных средств - моветон

Comment: Нужно вывести парное кол-во, или все-таки две последние?

Comment: я хочу изначально при создание контента для слайдера загрузить для него парное количество элементов. Вот поэтому собственно и задаю вопрос. Возможно есть готовая функция sql

Comment: нет, готовой функции SQL нет для такого, это никак не может быть даже из понимания всей парадигмы SQL. Это можно сделать на бэкэнде и выводить попарно уже на фронт данные. К примеру, циклом проходить по всему массиву последних новостей и делать из них пары, потом уже массив пар отдавать на фронт и там уже через цикл их выводить

Comment: понятно, спасибо!

Comment: А откуда вы берете эту таблицу `последние новости`? Вероятно, есть общая таблица новостей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним запросом я не знаю как это сделать.
Возможно, вам нужно получить сначала кол-во записей в таблице

```
select count(*) from table;
```

потом округлить до ближайшего четного

```
$count = ($count - ($count % 2));
```

и потом выбрать с лимитом

```
select * from table limit $count;
```

Comment: Да самый быстрый вариант, спасибо

Comment: В таком случае самая последняя новость в "последних новостях" и не отобразится.

Comment: добавить order by нужное_поле DESC перед limit и проблема решена

Comment: @WhoIsDT Два запроса (один на count, второй на данные) сложно назвать "самым быстрым вариантом". Действительно самым быстрым было бы получить просто все записи и если последняя запись оказалась без пары, то не выводить ее. Решается полностью в клиентском коде

Comment: @WhoIsDT, Для более быстрого решения, не используйте `*` в `count`.

Comment: @Mike вопрос стоял как получить четное кол-во. На вопрос дан ответ.
Когда у автора будут сотни новостей - все это будет не нужно и он будет получить заведомо лимитированное кол-во записей без шаманства с четными.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас производится только 1 запрос на странице, то лучше Одним запросом получить все записи и потом поделить их функцией array_chunk() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php

если запросы производятся через ajax, то стоит воспользоваться SQL конструкцией LIMIT OFFSET

Answer (score 1):

Можно и в один запрос:

```
select *
  from (
    select *, @cnt:=@cnt+1 num
      from table_c, (select @cnt:=0) x
  ) y
 where num<=@cnt-@cnt%2
```

Но лучше получить все и выбрасывать лишнюю запись уже на клиенте.