# Поиск записи по необходимой сумме столбца INT

Tags: mysql, запрос

Суть в следующем, есть ли возможность вычислить ID записи при получении необходимой суммы столбца B.

```
id | a | b
1  | 13| 23
2  | 4 | 45
3  | 5 | 25
4  | 2 | 34
5  | 6 | 55
6  | 1 | 13
```

И вот из такой таблица надо получить ID строки после суммы(B)>(необходимого_числа).
при сортировке, по ID по A или по B, неважно.
главное что бы после того как сумма перевалила за необходимую - скан останавливался и мы получали ID.
Помогите)) уже всю голову сломал

Comment: Вам нужна сумма нарастающим итогом. Есди у вас MySQL 8.0 используйте оконную (с предложением over()) функцию sum(). Если версия младше - то переменные, примерно как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/774188/194569 только вместо добавления 1, добавлять `b`

Comment: *при сортировке, по ID по A или по B, неважно* Если не указать конкретную сортировку (причём такую, что по ключу сортировки записи уникальны) - решение не имеет смысла. Можно просто проверить общую сумму, если она меньше заданной - вернуть NULL, а если больше - вернуть ЛЮБОЙ ID, поскольку всегда можно придумать сортировку такую, чтобы нужная сумма набиралась именно на этом ID.

Comment: @Akina, допустим сортировка по А. Каково решение при такой сортировке? т.к. скорее всего по ID записи не придётся сортировать!

Comment: @Mike, SELECT *,@cnt:=@cnt+B FROM `table`,(select @cnt:=0) x WHERE `id` = 12   
 Спасибо!

Comment: А сортировку-то забыл? в общем случае у тебя подсчёт пойдёт в неизвестно каком порядке. ``SELECT *,@cnt:=@cnt+B FROM `table`,(select @cnt:=0) x WHERE id = 12 ORDER BY a``.